# Loading my corpus with load_files scikit learn

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, dataset

I am trying to load my own corpus with the `load_files` option in `scikit` learn but I get none of it imported. I specified absolute path to the folder with my articles I would like to analyse

This is my code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
bunch = load_files('/home/fledrmaus/corpus/', shuffle = False)
```

However, I get this:

```
Out[39]: 
{
 'DESCR': None,
 'data': [],
 'filenames': array([], dtype=float64),
 'target': array([], dtype=float64),
 'target_names': []
}
```

I do not understand. Help would be appreciated.

regards,

guzden

Comment: is your directory structure in the required format?

Comment: Hey T, I figured out what was wrong. Did not have sub-folders of article categories. Gotta delete this question. Thanks for replying. :)